# How can i get name of the site definition configuration or site template from SPWeb?

Tags: spweb

I know that SPWeb have "WebTemplate" property and it always gives me string like "STS" or "MPS", but what I need is something like "STS#1". There is also "WebTemplateId" property, it gives WebTemplate Enumeration, which isn't useful for me.

Comment: Have a look here:  
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/which-site-template-is-a-site-using/8455#8455

Comment: This approach doesn't work correctly because "WebTemplateId" property returns the same value (1) for Team Site, Blank Site and Document Workspace.

Comment: Ok, it seems that my answer was wrong. I updated it with the one from Alexander. Thank's Alexander!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get WebTemplate and Configuration properties, then use `string.format("{0}#{1}", web.WebTemplate, web.Configuration )`.